# Magento 2.4.3-p1: Prices in frontend excluding tax but should be including tax

Tags: price, magento2.4, tax, magento2.4.3.p1

After upgrading the shop from version 2.3.2 to 2.4.3-p1 all the product prices in frontend are shown without tax. The price in backend is correct, all settings in **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax** are set to **Including Tax** and yet the prices are shown without tax on all pages (catalog, product details page, cart, checkout). The **Enable Cross Border Trade** setting is set to **Yes** but setting it to **No** doesn't help. We have 2 stores and I've checked all scopes but the settings in every scope seem to be correct.

What I tried and did not help

- downgrade to 2.4.2
- switch the **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax** settings to **Excluding Tax** and then switch it back again but that did not help
- reeindexing, removing cache, reimporting the products
- disable our custom modules

Magento version: 2.4.3-p1
PHP7.4
Mysql 8.0
Elasticsearch 7.9.3
Varnish 6.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was causing an outdated module. Once we updated it the price was corect again.

Comment: What module was it?